# JavaFx Application Developed in Windows 7 is not rendering properly in Windows 10

Tags: javafx-8

Hi StackOverFlow Team;

I am new to JavaFx and I have developed a POS (Point of Sale Application) in Windows 7 64 bit machine and I packaged the application with Netbeans Native packge or self-contained package. When I install the application in other W7 machines, the application runs fine as expected. However, when I install the same application in Windows 10 64 bits, the application still runs but it is rendering strangely.I was expecting the application to display exactly the same way it is displaying in W7 since it is native package. However when in W10,  It looses the original layout and some icons move to different location in the gui. Can anybody help me to solve this or point me to the solution?

Your support is highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can post a minimal amount of code that demonstrates the problem and which I can copy in order to try to reproduce the behavior on my Windows 7 and Windows 10 machines? Please read how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Pedro Vemba The monitor may be playing a role here do both machines use the same monitor? Just a guess but as mentioned show us the code for the controls like the Buttons and Anchor Pane styling are you using CSS or in line styling ?